# I can't get ExternalInterface.addCallback to work - trying to call an AS3 function from a js button click

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to use ExternalInterface.addCallback to allow js to call an as3 method. My code is as follows:

AS:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToActionscript", callFromJavaScript);

function callFromJavaScript():void{ 
circle_mc.gotoAndStop("finish"); 
}
```

JS:

```
<button type="button" onclick="callToActionscript()">Switch to square</button> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function callToActionscript() { 
flashController = document.getElementById("jstoactest")
flashController.sendToActionscript(); 
} 
</script>
```

It's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I set a isFlashReady flag in JS as FALSE. Then when your SWF is loaded, after Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE is fired, I add ExternalInterface.addCallback and flip isFlashReady flag to TRUE. This prevents a call to SWF before it's ready. You might want to throw alert() in JS functions below to see where it's stuck. Hope this helps.

JS:

```
var isFlashReady = false;
function thisMovie(movieName)
{
     if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1)
     return window[movieName];
}else{
     return document[movieName];
}
function callToActionScript(value)
{
     if(isFlashReady)
     {
          thisMovie("SWFID").sendToActionScript();
     }
}
function flashReady(value)
{
     isFlashReady = true;
}
```

AS:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
        try {
                ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendToActionScript", callFromJavaScript);
                flash.external.ExternalInterface.call(flashReady,true);
            } catch (error:SecurityError) {
                trace("A SecurityError occurred: " + error.message + "\n");
            } catch (error:Error) {
                trace("An Error occurred: " + error.message + "\n");
            }
} else {
            trace("External interface is not available for this container.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that AllowScriptAccess is set to "always" or "sameDomain" in embedding the flash and see if that helps. [livedocs](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000360.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is your SWF file being served from the same Domain as your HTML page?  If the domains differ then you will need to use [Security.allowDomain](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Security.html#allowDomain()) to allow the two to communicate.

Also, I've found the easiest way to debug Flash -> JavaScript communication is to use FireBug for Firefox. (sorry I can only post one link!)